# What are the provisions of Article 22 related to punitive detention?

Tags: indian-constitutional-law

I read that article 22 subclause 1 deals with punitive detention.

As far as my understanding Punitive detention is a type of imprisonment used to punish a person for an offense they committed after being found guilty in court.

Then how can 22(1) deal with punitive detention as it states that (i) no person who is arrested shall be detained in custody without being informed, as soon as may be, of the grounds for such arrest (If the person has been found guilty of the court then he is aware of his crime) (ii) Right to be produced before the magistrate within 244 hours of arrest. (If the person has been found guilty by the court then why should he be produced before a magistrate?)

So does article 22 not deal with punitive detention or which subclause deals with it?

Answer (score 1):

### Article 22 doesn’t mention “punitive” detention

It just refers to a “person who is arrested” and “detained in custody”. These are people who have not been found guilty by a court.